# Problema em ordenar dados resultantes do Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join, inner, order

Galera, tenho uma dúvida básica porém estou com uma dificuldade enorme em fazer uma consulta.

Tenho um sistema de Protocolos no qual os dados do protocolo ficam gravados numa tabela chamada PROTOCOLO e as atualizações de cada protocolo ficam em outra tabela chamada SITUACAO.

Tenho uma emissão de alerta que mostra todos os protocolos que estão a 7 dias sem movimentação, segue a minha consulta:

```
SELECT p.ID_PROTOCOLO, p.NUMERO, s.DATA_CADASTRO
FROM protocolo p
INNER JOIN situacao s ON s.ID_PROTOCOLO = p.ID_PROTOCOLO
where s.DATA_CADASTRO < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 day)
GROUP BY p.ID_PROTOCOLO
```

Necessito que esse INNER JOIN traga o último(mais atual) cadastro de SITUAÇÃO porém ele está trazendo sempre o primeiro cadastrado(mais antigo).

Já tentei fazer uma subconsulta e já tentei fazer um select dentro do INNER JOIN, e não tive sucesso.

Para quem tem experiência só de ver já vai saber a solução, porém para mim está bem difícil de resolver esse pequeno problema. Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou usar o `ORDER BY s.DATA_CADASTRO DESC`?